# How to make Primefaces Menu Item stay clicked

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I would like is it possible when i click on the MenuItem ( for example Active Requests) and the button colour changed to stay marked (clicked) also when i click a button in Active Request page to go for example to see Active Request Details. Now the behaviour is the following: I clicked Active Request, the button changed it colour and when i click Active Request Detail ( a button in Active Request page) the first item in Menu bar seems clicked (All Agencies) which is very confusing.

Here is my code for Menu bar:

```
  <h:form>
            <p:tabMenu activeIndex="#{param.i}">
                <p:menuitem value="All Agencies" outcome="allAgencies">
                    <f:param name="i" value="0" />
                </p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem value="Add Request " outcome="addRequest">
                    <f:param name="i" value="1" />
                </p:menuitem>
                <p:menuitem value="Аctive Requests" outcome="userActiveRequests">
                    <f:param name="i" value="2" />
                </p:menuitem>
            </p:tabMenu>
        </h:form>
```

I appreciate you willingness to help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried setting activeIndex manually?

Comment: No, can you give me an example how to do this?

Comment: I understood what do you mean. It works now. Big thanks.

Comment: please post your solution as an answer to your question and accept it, so you can help other people :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<p:commandButton value="Details" 
action="userActiveRequestDetails?faces-redirect=true i=2">
</p:commandButton>
```